# Actionscript 3 error code 1119 when dealing with this.parent?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, parent

I am fairly new to AS and am playing with a minesweeper game I found. For each cell on the game board, I have a movie clip (cell_mc) embedded with a dynamic text box (number_txt) for the numbers, a solid color square movie clip (block_mc), and a little flag to mark the bombed boxes (flag_mc). I also have a separate dynamic text box to count how many mines are left on the board (minecounter_txt).

My problem is that when I try to run the game, every where I have a "this.parent.flag_mc" or a "this.parent" with any of the mentioned elements, Flash returns an error code - "1119: Access of possibly undefined property flag_mc (or other element) through a reference with static type cell." And with minecounter_mc it returns "1119: Access of possibly undefined property flag_mc (or other element) through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObjectContainer"

I assumed that since it said it couldn't reference the elements with a static type, that it was unable to recognize them as dynamic. I searched for a solution, and read that it helps to declare the dynamic element before the parent, i.e. "MovieClip(this.parent.flag_mc), but it didn't help.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class cell extends MovieClip {

        public var state:Boolean;
        public var revealed:Boolean;
        public var xcor:uint;
        public var ycor:uint;
        public var marked:Boolean;
        public var cellValue:int;

        public function cell(corx:uint, cory:uint) {
            // constructor code

            this.state = false;
            this.revealed = false;
            this.marked = false;
            this.cellValue = 0;
            this.xcor = corx;
            this.ycor = cory;
            this.flag_mc.visible = false;
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, cellClicked);

    }//end of constructor

    private function cellClicked(event:MouseEvent):void{
        if(event.shiftKey){

            if(this.marked){
                this.flag_mc.visible = false;
                this.marked = false;
                this.parent.minecounter_txt.text = String(int(this.parent.parent.minecounter_txt.text) + 1);
            } else{
                this.flag_mc.visible = true;
                this.marked = true;
                this.parent.minecounter_txt.text = String(int(this.parent.parent.minecounter_txt.text) - 1);
            }

        } else{

            if(!state){
                openCell();
            } else{
                if(!this.marked){
                    this.parent.play_btn.visible = true;
                }
            }

        }
    }

    private function openCell(){
        if(!this.marked && !this.revealed){
            this.block_mc.visible = false;
            this.revealed = true;
            this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, cellClicked);
        }
    }

}//end of class

}//end of package
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.parent` will be null unless the movieclip is added to the parent's display list.

It would be better to pass the reference of the parent & store it in a class property.

```
var parentObj:Object = null;

// Constructor
public function cell(parentObj:Object, corx:uint, cory:uint) {

         this.parentObj = parentObj;

         //...
```

And call it as :

```
var cellObj = new cell(this, ...);
```

If you know which Class would be the parent, then you could also set the typeof parentObj to it.